# Jenkins pipeline optional boolean parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to utilize a custom function with a default boolean value that can be overridden. Issue is it doesn't override the default. All iterations match "else."

```
pipeline {

  agent {
    label 'any'
  }

  stages {
    stage('Foo') {
      steps {
        doThing('/opt/prod','athos',true)
        doThing('/opt/demo','aramis',true)
        doThing('/opt/test','porthos')
        doThing('/opt/dev','dartagnan')
      }
    }
  }
}

def doThing(def targetDir, def stackName, def prod=false) {
  if ( env.prod == true ) {
    sh """
      execute-bin \
        -Dbin.target=${targetDir} \
        -Dbin.stackName=${stackName} \
        -Dbin.prod=true
    """
  } else {
    sh """
      execute-bin \
        -Dbin.target=${targetDir} \
        -Dbin.stackName=${stackName}
    """
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try compare to the string value :

```
  if ( prod == 'true' )
```

This happens because environment variables are always strings, and true without qoutes is a boolean so its never equal:

consider this:

```
def doThing(def prod=false) {
  if ( prod == true ) {
    println 'TRUE'   
  } else {
    println 'FALSE'
  }
}

// this is how environment are passed into the pipeline from jenkins UI
doThing('true')
> FALSE
doThing('false')
> FALSE

// if environment variables were boolean (and they are not) it would be ok
doThing(true)
> TRUE
doThing(false)
> FALSE

// the current equality check is always false
println true=='true'
> false
println true=='false'
> false
```

Comment: propper way i belive is to convert String to Boolean like this
`if (env.prod.toBoolean()) {
}`

Answer (score 4):

You have in your if block `env.prod` variable and passing `true` to `prod`  **function variable `def prod`** which is different. This `prod` var **is only defined for `doThing` function scope** and it's different than `env.prod` or simply `prod` available in groovy code. If you won't change `env.prod` it always be else in `doThing()`. Either change its value somewhere in the code (depending or logic) or simpy try this:

```
pipeline {

  agent {
    label 'any'
  }

  stages {
    stage('Foo') {
      steps {
        doThing('/opt/prod','athos',true)
        doThing('/opt/demo','aramis',true)
        doThing('/opt/test','porthos')
        doThing('/opt/dev','dartagnan')
      }
    }
  }
}

def doThing(def targetDir, def stackName, def prod=false) {
  if ( prod == true ) {
    sh """
      execute-bin \
        -Dbin.target=${targetDir} \
        -Dbin.stackName=${stackName} \
        -Dbin.prod=true
    """
  } else {
    sh """
      execute-bin \
        -Dbin.target=${targetDir} \
        -Dbin.stackName=${stackName}
    """
  }
}
```

#### Edit

I will try to make it more clear. I know that you can refer to environment variables simply by its name:

> Environment variables are accessible from Groovy code as env.VARNAME
>   or simply as VARNAME. **You can write to such properties as well (only
>   using the env. prefix):**
>
> env.MYTOOL_VERSION = '1.33' node {   sh
>   '/usr/local/mytool-$MYTOOL_VERSION/bin/start' }

But there is a difference between global variables and variables accessible inside a function scope. If you would add assignment from `doThing()` `prod` variable to global `env.prod` variable it would also work

```
def doThing(def targetDir, def stackName, def prod=false) {
  env.prod = prod
  if ( env.prod == true ) {
    sh """
      execute-bin \
        -Dbin.target=${targetDir} \
        -Dbin.stackName=${stackName} \
        -Dbin.prod=true
    """
  } else {
    sh """
      execute-bin \
        -Dbin.target=${targetDir} \
        -Dbin.stackName=${stackName}
    """
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to @chenchuck's answer you may as well use `params.prod` which actually returns a `boolean` and therefore won't need a string compare:

```
def doThing(def targetDir, def stackName, def prod=false) {
  if ( params.prod == true ) {
  ...
```

However the `== true` will be obsolete. It can then be shortened to:

```
def doThing(def targetDir, def stackName, def prod=false) {
  if ( params.prod ) {
  ...
```

It's described under the `Pipeline Syntax->Global Variables Reference` link in your Pipeline job's dashboard. Scroll down until you find the description for the `params` global variable (the link to that should be `JENKINS_URL/job/globalSharedLib/pipeline-syntax/globals#params`). The following description I copied from my local Jenkins instance:

> params
>
> Exposes all parameters defined in the build as a read-only map with
>   variously typed values. Example:
>
> ```
> if (params.BOOLEAN_PARAM_NAME) {doSomething()}
> ```
>
> or to supply a nontrivial default value:
>
> ```
> if (params.get('BOOLEAN_PARAM_NAME', true)) {doSomething()}
> ```
>
> Note for multibranch (Jenkinsfile) usage: the properties step allows
>   you to define job properties, but these take effect when the step is
>   run, whereas build parameter definitions are generally consulted
>   before the build begins. As a convenience, any parameters currently
>   defined in the job which have default values will also be listed in
>   this map. That allows you to write, for example:
>
> ```
> properties([parameters([string(name: 'BRANCH', defaultValue: 'master')])])
> git url: '…', branch: params.BRANCH
> ```
>
> and be assured that the master branch will be checked out even in the
>   initial build of a branch project, or if the previous build did not
>   specify parameters or used a different parameter name.

Comment: This isn't working. Can you link the docs that reference this approach?

Comment: As written the documentation can be found in your Jenkins instance. Open a Pipeline job, click on the `Pipeline Syntax` link in the sidebar. Then choose the `Gobal Variables Reference` link in the sidebar. After that scroll down until you find the description of the `params` global variable. I updated the answer accordingly.